# Angular not working on IE9 possibly due to internal injector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a angular 1.3.15 application which doesn't work on Internet Explorer 9, I get a `Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference` error which points to this block of code in the angular core.

The error is thrown that much is executed correctly but I have no ideea what this function normally does and what's missing on IE9 for it to work.

```
function createInternalInjector(cache, factory) {

    function getService(serviceName, caller) {
      if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
        if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
          throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}',
                    serviceName + ' <- ' + path.join(' <- '));
        }
        return cache[serviceName];
      } else {
        try {
          path.unshift(serviceName);
          cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
          return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
        } catch (err) {
          if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
            delete cache[serviceName];
          }
          throw err;
        } finally {
          path.shift();
        }
      }
    }
```

As a final note I've included es5-shim and shams, I already use data-ng-* attributes I've read multiple articles about getting angular to work on IE9 but none of them describe a problem similar to this one so I'm left with only asking this question on SO.

Comment: Can you paste the code of yours that eventually calls this?

Comment: @MathewBerg My code doesn't explicitly call this, it's running automatically and I think it can't find a service to inject.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue by adding breakpoints and debugging till I found the name of the service it couldn't inject `$location` and this stemmed from me trying to use html5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

If I comment this and use the # routes the application works as far as I can tell, if anyone has a ideea on how to use html5mode in IE9  I'll mark your answer as the correct one as I don't want to answer my own question.